# How to establish connection between android phones using zoiper running Asterisk?

Tags: networking, ubuntu, virtualbox, asterisk

I have this scenario:

- 2 smartphones and 1 laptop, all in the same network.
- Both smartphones have Zoiper in order to comunicate with an asterisk server.

The laptop is running Mac OS (Host) and inside it has a VM running Ubuntu (Guest) with an asterisk server.

The asterisk server is simple and is already configured, and I can establish connection with a zoiper terminal inside the VM. My problem is when I try to establish connection with the Host and also the smartphones to the asterisk server.

How can i do it?

I'm trying to use a NAT network on VBox, since I think with bridged adapter I won't be able to connect the smartphones.

All I was able to do was establish connection between the Host and Guest using SSH, configuring a port forwarding for SSH on the NAT network.

Answer (score 0):

It depend of your connection settings, for virtualbox and laptop connected via dhcp to router simplest variant will be use virtualbox network type "bridged".

Comment: The thing is. If i connect the guest and the host via bridged adapter, i can't see how will i be able to connect to the asterisk server on the guest, using my smartphones.

Comment: Use bridged adapter and fixed ip address from same network. Virtualbox host-only network not designed for access from other hosts(phones) in same localnet. It is possible to setuped NATed network, but it not trivial and not so easy do describe. Just use bridged mode and think your asterisk is different hardware device with same router.